# UITabBarController selectedIndex/selectedViewController does not color tab on iOS 13

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, selecteditem, selectedindex

At app startup, on iOS 13, setting my `UITabBarController`'s `selectedIndex` or `selectedViewController` does show the correct view controller, but **all tab icons remain grey**.

I do this in `AppDelegate` and it's been working for years and still is working fine on iOS 12.

Even after setting the selected tab again after a seconds long delay (well after the app and UI are up and running), all icons remain grey.

All calls are done on the main thread.

Then, after a tap on a tab it turns blue and everything is fine.

Is this a bug or a feature of iOS 13 or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: faced the same problem, did you find solution?

Comment: @Abrcd18 Had a look.  Seems I deleted this feature (remembering which tab was last selected).  So at startup I just let it default to the first tab being selected.